# Can I store application data in Bigcommerce DB?

Tags: api, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I'm developing an application for Bigcommerce and I would like to store my own data in the Bigcommerce DB. Is this possible? Or I should store application data on the application side?

Comment: We do not offer a way for you to store information on the BigCommerce database. You will need to store it elsewhere.

Comment: Is the data specified per product?  Or just once for the entire application?

Answer (score 0):

If your application integrates against the Catalog, you can store metafields against Catalog objects: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/catalog.html#createvariantmetafield

These fields are intended to store extra data relevant to your application against a BigCommerce object. These fields will eventually come to most/all V3 APIs.